# Convert Entity object to JSON

Tags: java, json, spring

I need to convert entity object to json. I put

```
<bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <array>
            <bean class = "org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <ref bean="JacksonObjectMapper" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="JacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper" />
```

to servlet configuration file, so Spring could convert object to json format autonatically. But Spring does not do it. I also added jackson jar to project.

Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addData.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody GroupStudent addNewGroup(@RequestBody GroupStudent group) {
    return group;    
}
```

GroupStudent

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GroupStudent")
@NamedQueries({ 
@NamedQuery(name = "GroupStudent.getAllGroups", // get all groups
            query = "select g from GroupStudent g"),
@NamedQuery(name = "GroupStudent.getGroupByName", // get group by name
            query = "select g from GroupStudent g where g.groupStudentNumber = :name")
})
public class GroupStudent implements Serializable {
public GroupStudent() {}

public GroupStudent(String groupStudentNumber) {
    this.groupStudentNumber = groupStudentNumber;
}

// create connectivity with table Student
private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "groupStudent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
public Set<Student> getStudents() {
    return this.students;
}   

public void setStudents(Set<Student> students) {
    this.students = students;
}   

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "group_id_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "group_id_seq", sequenceName = "GroupStudent_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "GroupStudentId")
public Long getGroupStudentId() {
    return this.groupStudentId;
}

public void setGroupStudentId(Long groupStudentId) {
    this.groupStudentId = groupStudentId;
}

@Column(name = "GroupStudentNumber")
public String getGroupStudentNumber() {
    return this.groupStudentNumber;
}

public void setGroupStudentNumber(String groupStudentNumber) {
    this.groupStudentNumber = groupStudentNumber;
}

// table GroupStudent fields
private Long groupStudentId;
private String groupStudentNumber;
```

}

In browser I found that I have 406 error and error window error[object Object].

If anyone knows what the problem is, I will be gratfull for help.

Thank you.

Comment: 406 is Not Acceptable. How do you try to access your Controller url?

Comment: If you are about Ajax function:

function addGroupAjax() {
       var groupStudentNumber = $('#groupStudentNumber').val();
       
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/IRSystem/addData.html",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
        data: "{\"groupStudentNumber\":\"IS-02\"}",
        success: function(response) {
         
        },
        error: function(e) {
         alert("Error" + e);
        }
       });
      }

Comment: Ok. And what inside GroupStudent? Show me please. And I forgot to mention that you must have jackson library in your classpath.

Comment: I have added higher GroupStudent class. And i put jackson libraries to classpath

Answer (score 1):

If your object joined other table then you can only do this in the following way.

First, let’s annotate the relationship with @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference to allow Jackson to better handle the relation:

Here’s the “User” entity:

```
public class User {
    public int id;
    public String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    public List<Item> userItems;
}
```

And the “Item“:

```
public class Item {
    public int id;
    public String itemName;

    @JsonManagedReference
    public User owner;
}
```

Let’s now test out the new entities:

```
@Test
public void
  givenBidirectionRelation_whenUsingJacksonReferenceAnnotation_thenCorrect()
  throws JsonProcessingException {

    User user = new User(1, "John");
    Item item = new Item(2, "book", user);
    user.addItem(item);

    String result = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(item);

    assertThat(result, containsString("book"));
    assertThat(result, containsString("John"));
    assertThat(result, not(containsString("userItems")));
}
```

Here is the output of serialization:

```
{
 "id":2,
 "itemName":"book",
 "owner":
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"John"
    }
}
```

Note that:

@JsonManagedReference is the forward part of reference – the one that gets serialized normally.
@JsonBackReference is the back part of reference – it will be omitted from serialization.

Quoted from the link below. You can visit for more.

[Jackson – Bidirectional Relationships](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion)

Comment: Yes. I needed this `new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(item);` THank you

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestMapping(produces="application/json")` is what you need and DO NOT FORGET to make a POST request in your JS code (not GET).